# $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^3 - 5x^2}$ diverges

Tags: calculus

I need to show that

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^3 - 5x^2} $$

diverges.

It would be great if I could do it finding function $g(x) $ such that $g(x) \leq \frac{1}{x^3 - 5x^2}$ and  the integral of $g$ diverges. I've think of using $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^3}$, but since I need to consider $x \in [0,1]$, I think it won't work.

Should I conside another function like $\frac{1}{x^2}$ or there is a better way to choose one?

thanks in advance!

Comment: $\frac 1 {x^2}$ will work just fine.

Comment: For such problems, I think that partial fraction decomposition is great.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I know how to do using partial decomposition, I was just looking for an alternative way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas in our interval, doesn't only $x^2$ holds? Since $x^2 \geq 0$ and, as you noted, $x^3 \leq x^2$, isn't that true that $x^3 - 5x^2 \leq x^3 \leq x^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x^3 - 5x^2} \geq \frac{1}{x^2}$?

Comment: Yes, coffee had not hit yet. The relevant thing is that since $0\lt 5x^2-x^3\le 5x^2$, we have $\frac{1}{5x^2-x^3}\ge \frac{1}{5x^2}$.

Comment: Wait, what I said is no correct even for x = 1 (since $x^3 - 5x^2$ will be negative at the interval!) . I need to use the negative signal. we will take that it does not converges, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $0$, you have
$${1\over x^3 - 5x^2 } = {1\over x^2(x -5)}\sim -{1\over 5x^2}.$$
You know that $$\int_{0+} {dx\over x^p}$$
does not integrate at $0$ if $p \ge 1$, so this integral diverges.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can yoy give a bette explain why $ \frac{1}{x^2(x-5)} \sim \frac{-1}{5x^2}$ ? I mean, it is intuitively true, but I don't see how to explain it well.

Comment: As $x\to 0$, $x - 5 \to 5$ so $x-5\sim -5$ as $x\to 0$.